# Should I omit the else-statement when I throw an exception?

Tags: c#, if-statement, exception

Compare the two blocks of code below:

```
if (args.Length != 1)
{
    throw new ArgumentException();
}    
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0])
{
     throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
File f = new File(args[0]);
if (!f.Exists)
{
    throw new FileNotFoundException();
}
// Perform tasks on the file
```

and this:

```
if (args.Length != 1)
{
    throw new ArgumentException();
}    
else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0])
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
else
{
    File f = new File(args[0]);
    if (!f.Exists)
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }
    else
    {
        //Perform tasks on the file
    }
}
```

Which one is better (in terms of performance/readability)? I will not be catching the exceptions in my code since the application must have a file to operate on.

Comment: I like the first one because it's easier to see at a glance how the code flows ... really a matter of taste though, I think.

Comment: I prefer the first one as well.  The second sample just leads to [the arrowhead anti-pattern](http://lostechies.com/chrismissal/2009/05/27/anti-patterns-and-worst-practices-the-arrowhead-anti-pattern/).

Comment: That is what I am thinking too...hoping to get some opinions

Answer (score 4):

*Better* is highly subjective, so I won't say that one is better than the other. What I *can* say is that the else block in the second example is not *necessary*. I would personally prefer that code, because I think it is easier to read.

Comment: correct,readability is more preferred

Comment: is there any performance gain from omitting the else-statement?

Comment: The performance from omitting the else, would be near, if not, undetectable.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason for the `else`, since the program will stop once your throw an `exception`. It is safe to expect that, if the program has not closed by the time you get to the actual code, there were no errors.

For readability purposes I would omit the else block, as you can safely remove bloating from your code.

Comment: Yup I can see that too, but will there be any difference in terms of performance/readability?

Comment: As for readability, I would defiently recommend the the one without the else

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really matter which you use. The second works also if you refactor the code to not throw an exception (weird problems arise when you forget to insert the `else` then :-)). I would not expect any performance improvement by using the first statement - at least, not a noticable one.

It would, however, be a good idea to also pass an exception message to the exceptions thrown.